# Stripe.Js and setupIntents with handleCardActions

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a stripe.js/nodejs integration with paymentIntents that will prompt the user for 3D secure flow as needed when the paymentIntent is created. If the next_action.type comes back as "use_stripe_sdk" then I pass the paymentIntent client_secret to the stripe.js handleCardAction method and it does the popup and returns correctly. But, when I use the same flow for setupIntents, handleCardAction does nothing. Does setupIntents work with handleCardAction? I can't figure out why it wouldn't, it's the same flow, but maybe it's not supported for some reason? The other approach is to use the redirect_url approach and do it myself, but handleCardAction was really great. Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For SetupIntents you want to follow https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse which utilizes [confirmCardSetup](https://stripe.com/docs/js/setup_intents/confirm_card_setup). If for some reason you're doing manual confirmation, see the [API docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-confirm) for what will happen (you'll have to utilize the redirect url).